# Getting Warning for conflicting with the internal version provided by Android

Tags: android, elasticsearch, dependency-injection, android-gradle-plugin

Getting this warning

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

while adding elastic search dependency in gradle

```
    compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:rest:5.2.1'
```

Please help me how can i fix this

Comment: this is the origin for android studio. you should bear with it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one :

```
compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.10.2') {
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}
compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.10.2') {
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
```

Let me know if this works. For a more detailed answer please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31509229/7337391)