# Gradle build failed while running my android app

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have imported a branch from GIT HUB and trying to run that app. It is taking too much of time to build and finally giving me too many errors like **OUT of memory exceptions**. I am using android studio 2.2.3. and **build tool version** 25.0.2 and JavamaxheapSize is 4g. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

```
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:  at 
com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.utf8BytesToString(CstString.java:81)
Error:  at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.<init>(CstString.java:200)
Error:at`com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:371)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:262)
Error:  at 
com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
Error:  at  `com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
Error:  at 
om.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
Error:  at 
com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:491)
Error:  at 
com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
Error:  at 
com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:772) 
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
Error:  at 
com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1700)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:755)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:723)
Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
Error:  at   
Error:  at `.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
Error:  at `
```

`com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
  
    ``

Comment: Search on google  `OUT of memory`

Comment: care to post your gradle file to double check the heap size is set correctly, very unlikely you are exceeding 4g. Also the memory on the machine is 4gb or more correct?

The line `Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.` You need to exclude some libraries from including other modules, this link should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295066/android-dependency-is-ignored-for-release