# HttpEntity class file error

Tags: java, android, apache

I am building an  Android application for uploading images and videos to a server.
Everything looks fine, but when i try to run or debug the app i get this error.

Error:(15, 8) error: cannot access HttpEntity
class file for org.apache.http.HttpEntity not found.

I have googled and tried many solutions including this  [How do I properly import HttpClient from org.apache on Android using gradle build file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775747/how-do-i-properly-import-httpclient-from-org-apache-on-android-using-gradle-buil)

I have extended the Apache HttpMultipartEntity class to create my custom MultiPartEntity class. I have also included the httpmime-4.2.6.jar file as a library.Can someone help me out.

Comment: do tell me when you find the solution... Even I am eaferly waiting for this one... hehe

Comment: Apache Http Module has been removed from android API Level 23. So you need to find another alternative now.

Answer (score 0):

See in your `build.gradle` file whether the `minSdkVersion` is `23` and if yes, declare the following compile-time dependency in the `android` section of your `build.gradle`

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

ie, the android section in your `build.gradle` file would be like,

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

along with other entries.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client), the **Apache libraries were deprecated and removed from the Android SDK in Android MarshMallow**.