# How to import org.apache.httpcomponents using Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Just trying to make some POST requests in an Android app. I was testing with `HttpClient 4.5.3` (https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) in a standalone script. Everything worked, but when I tried to add it to the Android app, I found out I need to add some repackaged dependency due to versioning issues. So I added

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

in Gradle and synced it without issues. However, I can't `import` any of the classes I need to do what I need. These are the imports I need:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity; // "HttpEntity" is highlighted red
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly import HttpClient from org.apache on Android using gradle build file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775747/how-do-i-properly-import-httpclient-from-org-apache-on-android-using-gradle-buil)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34153044/3166697
check `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
android {
    ... 
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

Comment: Really? Legacy?